# Mysql Replication, 2 databases, 2 ways?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have 2 MYSQL server.

MySQL#1
and 
MySQL#2

MySQL#1 hosts a database which has been replicated thanks to this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql to MySQL#2. Let's name this first database DATABASE1

MySQL#2 hosts another database DATABASE2 which has nothing to do with DATABASE1.

Is it possible to replicate as master-slave without creating conflict with the first replication, to let MySQL#1 becoming the slave for MySQL#2 ?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. I used to do that myself. There are several ways to do so.

1. At slave server configuration file, add  `replicate-ignore-db = DATABASE_YOU_WANT_TO_IGNORE`
2. At master server configuration file, only log the database you want replicate to slave. `binlog_do_db = DATABASE_YOU_WANT_TO_REPLICATE`

Not only you can specified what database to repliace, you can even specified only what table in particular database that you want to replicate. See also [replicate_wild_do_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-ignore-table)

**Further Reading**

- [Replication Slave Options and Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html)
- [How To Set Up Selective Master Slave Replication in MySQL](http://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-set-up-selective-master-slave-replication-in-mysql/)
- [Why MySQL’s binlog-do-db option is dangerous](http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/)